# symfony services.yml difference between/utility of name and resource

Tags: symfony

I'm new to symfony, I noticed that in services.yml we usually define each entry by a name (for example App\Controller) and then add the path to the file/folder in the resource attribute, for example :

```
App\Controller :
    resources: ../../Controllers/*
```

isn't this some kind of repetitive ? what is the use of the name we give at the beginning ?
Thank you

Comment: Autowire uses the name as a namespace prefix when determining which classes are controllers.  If you change it to something like App\Controllerx then you will get "Expected to find class "App\Controllerx\IndexController" in file" error messages.  Note also that in Symfony, directory names tend to be singular so you would normally see Controller (not Controllers) in the resources section.  One final note, unless you need to support legacy code, then you should use the latest version (4.x) for learning.  Ignore tutorials which use older versions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer; unfortunately, I'm working on a project that has legacy code :/